# How can I handle a new-lined string and put it into a variable?

Tags: javascript, java, string, line

For example I have this set of codes:

```
 3599415
 2483198
 3599415
 3599415
  932194
  932194
 3599415
```

What can I do to put this set in a single String variable (in Java or Javascript) to handle it and do a text editing that I need?

Comment: Use string "concat" to make all strings on different lines as one string. This function is there in both Javascript and Java. And them do whatever text editing you need. Search for- concatenating strings in Javascript.

Comment: Well Generally for reading line wise data as mentioned you can use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` implementation and do the manipulation inside it

Comment: thx, can you post an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just assign it like this:

**For Javascript**

```
var str = "3599415\n" + 
    "2483198\n" +
    "3599415\n" +
    "3599415\n" +
    "932194\n" +
    "932194\n" +
    "3599415";
```

You can do the same for Java even if using a `StringBuilder` will consume less memory and be fatser.